# Add bootstrap classes based on the parent div class - Prefers a SASS only solution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

My div structures is as follows and my project runs using Angular2.

```
<div class="card-content">
  <div>
    <h4 class="card-title">
         <a href="#pablo">Cinnamon Lodge - Habarana</a>
    </h4>
    <div class="card-description color-overwrite">Double Room</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What I need to do is, when I change the 'card-content' class to 'stripe-card-content' some bootstrap classes needs to be added to inner divs as follows.**

Using typescript I can change the class to 'stripe-card-content'. ***But I prefer a SASS only solution to add bootstrap classes based on the parent div class.*** Any help ?

```
<div class="stripe-card-content">
  <div class = "row">
    <h4 class="card-title col-lg-6">
         <a href="#pablo">Cinnamon Lodge - Habarana</a>
    </h4>
    <div class="card-description color-overwrite col-lg-6">Double Room</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading the appropriate imports, you could just extend Bootstrap classes, like the following:

```
.stripe-card-content {

    > div {
       @extend .row;
    }
}
```

If I recall correctly, however, Bootstrap dynamically builds out the cols, so that one may be more tricky.  Let me look into it while you try extends on the row.

Comment: Wait, you are using v4, or no?  Bootstrap 3 is LESS, and with so you wouldn't be able to import/extend, like above.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.5.

Comment: There is a [bootstrap-sass repo for v3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) and you should be able to do the @extend once you install that package and import it for usage.